# SPARQL Extract Entities from dbpedia In Python

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to extract **Entities/Concepts** for the word **Fish**  Using the below code, But i am getting like

```
Fish
سمك
Fische
Pisces
Poisson
Pesce
Vissen (dieren)
Ryby
Peixe
Рыбы
鱼
```

I am expecting like **cAT FISH, GOLD FISH, GREEN FISH, FISHING**. how do I do that?

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, JSON

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery("""
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    SELECT *

    WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Fish> rdfs:label ?name }
""")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()

for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
    print(result["name"]["value"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is asking for all `rdfs:label` values for the entity `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Fish>`.  I think what you're wanting is something like --

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?label ?entity
WHERE
 { ?entity rdfs:label ?label 
   FILTER ( regex ( ?label, "fish", "i" ) ) 
 }
ORDER BY ?label
```

You can add a `LIMIT 10` or similar line to get a faster (incomplete) result.

You can also use a Virtuoso built-in-function (`bif:contains`) instead of the `FILTER ( regex (...) )`, to get faster results from DBpedia or other Virtuoso-powered endpoints, as --

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?label ?entity
WHERE
 { ?entity rdfs:label ?label .
   ?label bif:contains "fish"
 }
ORDER BY ?label
```

Comment: I get this error
Response:
b'Virtuoso S1T00 Error SR171: Transaction timed out\n\nSPARQL query:\n\n    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n    SELECT ?label ?entity\n    WHERE{ ?entity rdfs:label ?label \n    FILTER ( regex ( ?label, "fish", "i" ) ) }\n    ORDER BY ?label\n'

`

Comment: This is my code!
``sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery("""
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    SELECT ?label ?entity
    WHERE{ ?entity rdfs:label ?label 
    FILTER ( regex ( ?label, "fish", "i" ) ) }
    ORDER BY ?label
""")
sparql.setReturnFormat(JSON)
results = sparql.query().convert()

for result in results["results"]["bindings"]:
    print(result["name"]["value"])

Comment: I've added some other options to my answer. Note that your code and error get rather scrambled through the comment area here; better to edit such details into your question, and just comment to note that such edit has been made.

Comment: Hey Thanks, Second One worked for me. Can u suggest any tutorials/Videos/Materials where i can learn more. I want to extract subnets and many more stufs

Comment: Start with [SPARQL 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/)... There are lots of tutorials and videos. You might also try using different tools, like the graphical query builder [iSPARQL (available on DBpedia)](http://dbpedia.org/isparql), or the Virtuoso FCT browser (also [available on DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/fct/))...